# WebClientExtensions - DownloadDataTask

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, extension-methods, task-parallel-library

I may be missing something basic but how come does this method:

```
namespace System.Net
{
    public static class WebClientExtensions
    {        
        public static Task<byte[]> DownloadDataTask(this WebClient webClient, string address)
        {
            return DownloadDataTask(webClient, new Uri(address));
        }
    }
}
```

is called like this:

```
return new WebClient().DownloadDataTask(url)
```

This was taken from the ParallelExtensionsExtras Tour - #16 - Async Tasks for WebClient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such method is called an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx). It is distinguished by having `this` in front of the first parameter and you can call it as if it was an instance method on that parameter.

So, the code you wrote:

```
new WebClient().DownloadDataTask(url)
```

is actually exactly the same as:

```
WebClientExtensions.DownloadDataTask(new WebClient(), url)
```

The advantage is that it is a nicer syntax. For example, pretty much all of LINQ is also based on extension methods.